# How to take input multiple times even after the execution of program in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, input

so I was writing this program to find the number of times a  digit is repeated in a number.How can I ask the user to enter inputs again and again even after the execution at the first time

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rem,flag,n;
    int frequency[10]={0};
    printf("enter a number");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>0){
        rem=n%10;
        frequency[rem]++;
        n=n/10;
    }
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
    if(frequency[i]>1){
        flag=1;
        printf("%d is repeated %d times",i,frequency[i]);
        
    }
 }
    if(flag==0){
        printf("no number is repeated");
    } 
     
     
 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can try using while-do

Comment: In which portion of the code should I apply this?

Comment: Around the part that you wish to repeat

Comment: Rename your `main()` function as, for example, `work()` and write `int main(void) { int flag; do { flag = work(); } while (flag != 0); return 0; }`

Comment: You already understand iteration because you have used both `while` and `for` loops.  _Iteration_ is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to wrap your code in a `while (1)` loop (loop forever). I've added an extra check: if a user enters the number `0`, the program will break out of the loop and exit. There has to be *some* way to stop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    while (1){
        int rem,flag=0,n;
        int frequency[10]={0};

        printf("enter a number");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        if (n==0){
            break;
        }

        while(n>0){
            rem=n%10;
            frequency[rem]++;
            n=n/10;
        }
     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
        if(frequency[i]>1){
            flag=1;
            printf("%d is repeated %d times",i,frequency[i]);
            
        }
     }
        if(flag==0){
            printf("no number is repeated");
        } 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For a cleaner solution, you may want to create a function for everything within the `while` loop, and call that function.

Side note: `flag` has to be set to `0` at the start of the loop.